# watching for changes in ngModel.$invalid in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which replaces a `select` element with a custom input control.   Here's a simplified version of it:

```
angular.module('MyModule', []).directive('reflector', function($timeout) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            element.insertAfter('<input type=text id="new-' + attrs.id + '" />');
            element.hide()
        }
    };

});
```

I'd like this custom input control to reflect the valid/invalid state of the original select element, i.e. add the ng-invalid class when the base element is invalid.

Is there any way to watch for changes to `ngModel.$invalid`?   I know I can do `scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, ...)`, but that gives me the model data, not the form element's valid/invalid state..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can watch all the attributes from the [ngModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController):

```
$scope.$watch(function(){return ngModel.$invalid;},function(newVal,oldVal){ ...
```

And `ngModel` sets the following css classes onto the element: ng-valid, ng-invalid, ng-dirty, ng-pristine.