# Angular directive not watching

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I'm using a directive in AngularJS, and I'm trying to check if my field is $dirty, if that's true i want to log a message and when it changes i want to show another message (That sentence will be replaced later for something more complex).

I want to reuse in all my inputs my directive but i can't. Thanks in advance.

```
<input ng-edited ng-model="stakeholder.nombre" name="nombre" type="text">
```

And my directive is this:

```
MetronicApp.directive('ngEdited', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: ['^form', 'ngModel'],
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, req) {
            scope.elemDirty = req[1].$dirty;
            scope.elemName = req[1].$name;
            var doFunction = function () {
                if (scope.elemDirty) {
                    console.log("true");
                } else {
                    console.log("false");
                }
            };
            scope.$watch(scope.elemName, doFunction, true);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `req[1]` would be in this example.  usually a controller is passed as the 4th argument to the link function.

Comment: @Claies I'm sending two items by 4th arg: form and ngmodel, u can see it in require

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925192/watching-for-changes-in-ngmodel-invalid-in-angular-directive), why not try

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
    var doFunction = function (isDirty) {
        if (isDirty) {
            console.log("true");
        } else {
            console.log("false");
        }
    };
    scope.$watch(function(){return ngModel[1].$dirty;},doFunction);
}
```

[See plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2tdZtluVzcDrtvOvVE38?p=preview)

**Edit**

I noticed that in your question you are trying to watch change to the element's name. I'm not sure how you would be changing that attribute, but if you are, use [attrs.$observe](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes)

```
attrs.$observe('name', doFunction);
```

Comment: nope, it's not working :-(, still not watching changes

Comment: @JeanCedron the plunker works, can you please explain what does not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a parameter (as opposed to a string), you need to return it from a function:

```
scope.$watch(function () {
    return scope.elemName;
}, doFunction, true);
```

Comment: i also try this but It's not working, it's not watching any change

Comment: @JeanCedron Can you provide a fiddle ?